# Quantum Joke (not a real joke, not a riddle)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, quantum-states

Supposing I want to make a quantum joke, like writing this on a coffee machine:

$$| \text{Status}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\ \big( | \text{Working}\rangle \color{red}{\pm}  | \text{Down}\rangle \big) \, ,$$

should I choose the $\color{red}{+}$ or the $\color{red}{-}$ sign, or is it the same? Why?

Comment: The sign indicates [singlet/triplet states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_state).

Comment: Well, if all you're going to do is make a direct measurement of whether you're working or down, the sign doesn't matter for the outcome.

Comment: States don't have to be normalised.  So you don't need the root two.  But it adds a nice touch, a note of misplaced precision....  By the same token, you could multiply |working> by the imaginary unit $i$ to suggest that the status is a complicated affair, and the idea that it would  be working is purely imaginary....

Comment: As someone who is not familiar with quantum physics, this joke gives me a headache, along with the answers. Could someone give me a <500 chars explanation of this joke?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Understanding quantum physics doesn't make it funny either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The signs are important for fixing an out of order machine. Define the states $|\pm\rangle$ as:

$$|\pm\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\left |\text{Working}\right\rangle\pm \left |\text{Down}\right\rangle\right]$$

And we define the observable $O$ as:

$$O = |+\rangle\langle + |\  - \  |-\rangle\, \langle -|$$

Suppose then that coffee machine is out of order. To fix it, you measure $O$ and then you measure if it is working, if not you repeat the procedure of measuring $O$ and then checking if it is working. At each step you have 50% probability that it will be found to be working.

Comment: quantum machines seem to be really easy to fix via brute force!

Comment: Awesome answer! Ahaha nice!

Comment: How does the protocol for fixing the machine depend on whether the machine starts in state $|+\rangle$ or $|-\rangle$?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you don't want a quantum superposition, but just a statistical mixture:

$$\rho = \begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$$

Although I'm not 100% sure that this will describe your situation any better...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare indeterminacy and a probability of being either working or down you should use the vector notation:

```
       (working )
```

Status> =

```
       ( down)
```

Status being the column vector analogous to the column state vector of the wavefunction in [a matrix representation](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node246.html)

The user would be the operator :)